# Parse data export not working

Tags: parse-platform

I clicked "export the data" then after seconds it said "check your email for a download link". Just I never got that email. I've tried many times since last week. It was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is working fine. Try double checking your spam folders. Maybe since you've received so many similar messages, they've been flagged as spam.

Comment: I did. they are not in the spam folder.